# \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat not working

Tags: floats, captions, newfloat

I'm trying to create a custom environment called `graph` and underline the label before the colon. This is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ulem}

\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{graph}{tbph}{log}
\floatname{graph}{Graph}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{test}{\uline{#1 #2}}
\captionsetup[graph]{labelformat=test}

\begin{document}
    \begin{graph}[h]
    \caption{Testing}
    \end{graph}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the float name "Graph" completely disappears and I'm left with " 1: Testing". How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You have found an incompatibility between the `caption` and the `float` package regarding `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat`. I will fix this either today or tomorrow. See also: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/67

Comment: ...done. Uploading a new version including this bugfix is planned for KW 1.

Comment: Fixed with caption.sty v3.4c which I have uploaded to CTAN today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do that with `floatrow`, it works. Caveat: `float` is not compatible with `floatrow`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{ulem}

\DeclareNewFloatType{graph}%
{placement=tbph,fileext=gph,name=Graph}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{test}{\uline{#1 #2}}
\captionsetup[graph]{labelformat=test}

\begin{document}

    \begin{graph}[h]
    \caption{Testing}
    \end{graph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, `\newfloat` fails to define `\graphname`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % <----

\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{graph}{tbph}{loh} % <----
\floatname{graph}{Graph}
\newcommand{\graphname}{Graph}% <----

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{test}{\uline{#1 #2}}
\captionsetup[graph]{labelformat=test}

\begin{document}

\begin{graph}[h]
\caption{Testing}
\end{graph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed the extension for the new float type, using `log` doesn't seem like a good idea because this conflicts with the standard log file produced by TeX.

I also recommend to use the option `normalem`, in order to avoid that italic is rendered as underline.

Comment: For whatever reason, float names defined with `\floatname` offered by the `float` package will be defined as `\fname@#1`. The `caption` package currently does not respect this when using `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat`. I will fix this. (See also my comment below the question.) Until then, using `\newcommand{\graphname}{Graph}` looks like a good workaround for me, so I recommend this solution until the fix is avaliable.